# how to display one row from SQLite database to textview/edittext

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm very new to android and about to create an app which holds customers and then related to it some actions.
My current unsolvable problem: After inserting customer data into database I want to switch the view and display the last entry with all fields. The inserted values like title, name but also automatically created fields like id and date. I can see that the data are in the database when I pull the database file from the DDMS but I don't know how to retrieve and display them in the desired view.
I saw dozens of examples for passing it to a listview but I couldn't find any example which would suit my needs. Maybe it's because I don't know how to ask correctly for it. If so, please point me in the right direction.

My DatabaseHelper:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;



public class DbHelper  {

public static final String TABLE_CUSTOMERS = "customers";
public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATE = "date";

 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myround.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " (" + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_TITLE + " VARCHAR, "
        + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATE + " VARCHAR);";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CUSTOMERS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DbHelper(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public DbHelper open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long createCustomer(String Title, String FirstName, String LastName,
        String Date) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_CUSTOMER_TITLE, Title);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, FirstName);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, LastName);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATE, Date);

    long id = mDb.insert(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, null, initialValues);
    return id;

}


public Cursor displayLastCustomer() {

      Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, new String[] {COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID,
        COLUMN_CUSTOMER_TITLE, COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, COLUMN_CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATE},
        null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToLast();
      }
      return mCursor;
     }


}
```

And my CustomerHelper:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomerHelper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static final String TAG = "CustomerHelper";
EditText txtTtitle, txtFirstName, txtLastName,
          editID, editTitle, editFirstName, editLastName, editDate;
Button btn_add_customer_to_db;
DbHelper dbHelper;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_new_customer);
    txtTtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    txtFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_first_name);
    txtLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_last_name);
    editID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ntxt_customer_id);
    btn_add_customer_to_db = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_customer_to_db);
    btn_add_customer_to_db.setOnClickListener(this);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.open();

}

private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btn_add_customer_to_db) {
        String Title = txtTtitle.getText().toString();
        String FirstName = txtFirstName.getText().toString();
        String LastName = txtLastName.getText().toString();
        String Date = getDateTime();

        long id = dbHelper.createCustomer(Title, FirstName, LastName, Date);
        if (id < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success - Record added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }

    }

}

}
```

I'm looking for a solution to implement this view with the last entry into my CustomerHelperClass so that I can also modify or delete this entry.

For Inserting new customer I have add_new_customer.xml and I want to switch view to update_customer.xml with the last entry displayed. Both of them have the text fields for title, name etc

update_customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/update_customer_xml_title"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_activity_to_customer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/add_activity_to_customer_sm_btn"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_view_customer_management"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/go_to_customer_mgmt"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_main_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/go_to_main_menu"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_customer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/delete_customer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_customer_changes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/delete_customer"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/delete_customer"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:text="@string/save_customer_changes" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/save_customer_changes"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ntxt_customer_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ntxt_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ntxt_customer_id"
            android:hint="@string/title"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ntxt_first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ntxt_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ntxt_last_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ntxt_first_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/last_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ntxt_customer_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ntxt_last_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="date"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

edit:

```
 } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success - Record added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            setContentView(R.layout.update_customer);

        }

    }

    DbHelper dbHelperInstance = new DbHelper(this); // Assuming it's running
                                                    // in an Activity
    Cursor cursor = dbHelperInstance.displayLastCustomer();
    if (cursor != null) {
        EditText editTextFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ntxt_first_name);
        editTextFirstName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME)));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You simply need to run the query against your database, using your `DbHelper` (and the underlying static class) and from the resulting `Cursor` manipulate the data anyway you want to.
Hopefully this article can help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I looked through this tutorial and even tough it's interesting, it doesn't solve my current problem.

Comment: Let me put it this way, I do understand the structure how it should go I'm simply having troubles to translate these thoughts into actual programming language. I'm still in a learning mode which is pretty much copy/paste/adjust and then see what happens and get an understanding about it. So, what I'm looking for is an actual example how to solve my problem.

Comment: When I add a line in my customerHelper like setContentView(R.update_customer); after the last command "Toast.makeText... " then it switches the view correctly but all the fields are empty. I believe with the last method in my DatabaseHelper "public Cursor displayLastCustomer()" I should actually get the correct row but I have NO IDEA at all how to tell the programm to fill the lines with the content of that row. So, any help with an example would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you post your `R.update_customer`.xml file we can post exactly what you need to write. But basically it boils down to calling `View viewToPopulate = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID); viewToPopulate.setText(mCursor.getString(YOUR_COLUMN_ID);`

I'll answer the question fully, when you update it.

Comment: Hi NitroNbg, I added the update_customer.xml and now I'm really curious where to put the View viewToPopulate and what would be the R.id.Your_View_Id. I guess I saw similar things while searching for a solution but I couldn't figure out which value to put and where to place it. So, if you put an example it would be nice to have the first lines for setText (ID and Title) if there are differences and then of course a hint where to put it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can build upon this answer, if you need further guidance, feel free to comment.

Let's assume you want the `EditText` with id `ntxt_first_name` to be populated with customer name. You'd write this code after you call `displayLastCustomer()`

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelperInstance = new DbHelper(this); //Assuming it's running in an Activity
Cursor cursor = dbHelperInstance.displayLastCustomer();
if(cursor != null) {
    EditText editTextFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ntxt_first_name);
    editTextFirstName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME)));
}
```

The above snippet tries to find the `View` (`EditText`) with id `ntxt_frist_name` within the inflated View hierarchy that was supplied using the `setContentView(int resourceId)` method (hopefully you have supplied `R.layout.update_customer` as its parameter. Then it simply sets its `mText` field to the value it obtains from the entry `cursor` is currently pointing at (set to last entry in the query by your `displayLastCustomer()` method) for the column `DbHelper.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME`.

Like I already wrote, I hope you can get from this snippet how to populate other Views obtaining data from other columns in your `Cursor` object.

Cheers and good luck!

EDIT: In case you are not running this code inside an `Activity` object (or object of a class derived from it) , you need to obtain the `Context` of the `Activity` which has the `update_customer.xml` file inflated.

Comment: obviously I still miss something. I added the lines into CustomerHelper (see last edit) but it crashes the app. Just changing view with setContentView works fine but when adding the additional code it crashes.

Comment: Can you post stack trace after it crashed? It'll be much easier to debug, but I am willing to bet that `DbHelper` constructor is the problem.